# Java cannot get action/key listener to work

Tags: java, object, actionlistener, keylistener, pong

I am coding a Java pong game I am stuck on how to get the player paddle to move. I for some reason cannot get the program to notice the key inputs.

```
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Pong {

     Board board = new Board();  


    
    public void frame() {
         JFrame b = new JFrame("Pong");
         b.setSize(905,705);
         b.setLocation(300,60);
         b.setResizable(false);
         b.setVisible(true);
         b.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);        
         b.add(board);

         

    }

    public static  void main(String[] args) {
        Pong start = new Pong();
        start.frame();





    }


}
```

The board class

```
public class Board extends JPanel{
       public int playerScore = 0;
       public int opponentScore = 0;
       Player player = new Player();
       int test = 1;
       private Timer timer;
       private int time = 100;{
          timer = new Timer(time, player);
          timer.start();
        }
       public void paint(Graphics g) {
           Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

           board(g);
           g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
          // player.playerGenerate();
           g2d.fill(player.player);
            g.fillRect(30, test, 20, 20);
            player.paint(g);
            control();
    
          //repaint();
           }
           
       

       
       public void board(Graphics g) {
           Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
           
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 900, 900);
            Stroke stroke1 = new BasicStroke(4f);
            
            g2d.setColor(Color.white);
            g2d.setStroke(stroke1);
             
            g2d.drawRect(20, 50, 850, 600);
            g2d.setColor(Color.white);
            
            float[] dashingPattern2 = {10f, 4f};
            Stroke stroke2 = new BasicStroke(4f, BasicStroke.CAP_BUTT,
                    BasicStroke.JOIN_MITER, 1.0f, dashingPattern2, 0.0f);
             
            g2d.setStroke(stroke2);
            g2d.drawLine(435, 50, 435, 650);
            g.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.PLAIN,30));
            g.drawString(""+playerScore, 20, 35);
            g.drawString(""+opponentScore, 855, 35);
          


       }
       
       public void control() {
           if (player.down == true) {
               
               player.playerYpos = player.playerYpos = player.playerYpos -10;
               repaint();

           
           }
       }
}
```

And finally the player class.

```
public class Player extends JPanel  implements KeyListener,ActionListener{
    //Board theBoard = new Board();    

    public boolean down = false;
    public boolean up = false;
    public int playerXpos = 45;
    public int playerYpos = 300;
    public int playerWidth = 15;
    public int playerHeight = 80;
    Rectangle player = new Rectangle(playerXpos,playerYpos,playerWidth,playerHeight);
    

    // Board theBoard = new Board();
    public void playerGenerate() {
        playerXpos = 45;
        playerYpos = 300;
        playerWidth = 15;
        playerHeight = 80;
        
    //Rectangle r = new Rectangle(playerXpos,playerYpos,playerWidth,playerHeight);
    }
    


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (down) {
                
                down = true;

                if(up != true) {
                    down = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    up = true;
                    down = false;
                
                    
                }

            }
            
            if (up) {
                
                up = true;

                if(down != true) {
                    up = true;

                }
                else
                {
                    up = false;
                    down = true;
                
                    
                }

            }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {

            for(int r = playerYpos;r >=0;r--) {
                if(r==0) {
                    playerYpos = playerYpos -20;
                    
                }
                
                else {
                    playerYpos =    playerYpos -1 ;

                }
                
                if(playerYpos < 50){
                    playerYpos = 50;
                }
            }
                //repaint();
            
        }
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {

            for(int r = playerYpos;r >=0;r--) {
                if(r==0) {
                    playerYpos = playerYpos +20;
                    
                }
                
                else {
                    playerYpos =    playerYpos -1 ;
                    System.out.print("down");

                }
                
                if(playerYpos > 800){
                    playerYpos = 800;
                }
            }
                //repaint();
            }
        }
    

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
}
```

I tried googling around and looked at code that went with a similar approach of implementing action/key listener in the player/paddle class. I assume there is something minor and small I am just not seeing.

Comment: You never add the keylistener to the object

Comment: @Jens you mean in the board class? that has no effect on the code really it was just there to try and maybe see if it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have just wrote the method names. You need to register action/key listener to a particular swing component which you want to listen. 
Suppose if your JComponent is JButton named btnPlayer you need to register the action performed event like : 
`private void btnPlayerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {....`  
`...}`

You can add action listener from swing design. Right click on the JComponent -> Events -> ActionPerformed. 
It will register click event for the component. Adding events through the properties is a better option.

Comment: A bit hard for me to understand what you mean but I will take a look and read up on it thank you.

Comment: Can you provide some more of your design and code so that i can help you out

Comment: my apologies for a late reply. I saw what you mean later I will probably re ask my question later but.

In short I notice how I didn't register actionlistener like you said, however I cannot get the code to wwork when I try and make it so the player class is the one that moves the player padel